# why a limit on passband in spectral masks?

Tags: power-spectral-density

I was wondering why there is a usually flat limit on passband of every spectral masks.

For sidebands it makes sense but for passband not so much.

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not quite sure I understand your question.

Comment: maybe you could also illustrate with a counter-example that you think would make more sense?

Comment: I mean I do not understand putting a flat limit at the passband in spectral masks. For example, I sea here and there that scramblers can avoid having spectral lines in passband to help us meet the regulations' spectral masks. (and I know they have other benefits.) I wonder why.

Comment: but, what would be the alternative? How would you define that limit else? The flat spectral mask "No signal might ever exceed a spectral power density of so and so many dBm/Hz", and that applies to all signals, no matter whether they're narrowband (and hence spectral peaks) or wideband. Not quite sure what the alternative would be

Comment: I do NOT say "it should not be flat,"
I say "there should not be a limit there."